# How to trim newlines from String?

Tags: rust

Currently my code looks like this:

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let result_version = Command::new("git")
        .arg("--version")
        .output()
        .unwrap();

    let rc_version = result_version.status;
    println!("{}", rc_version);

    let mut stdout_version = str::from_utf8(&result_version.stdout).unwrap().to_string();
    let stdout_version_trimmed= trim_newline(stdout_version);

    println!("'{}'", stdout_version_trimmed);
}

fn trim_newline(s: &mut String) {
    if s.ends_with('\n') {
        s.pop();
        if s.ends_with('\r') {
            s.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately the compiler gives me:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:15:46
   |
15 |     let stdout_version_trimmed= trim_newline(stdout_version);
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                              |
   |                                              expected `&mut std::string::String`, found struct `std::string::String`
   |                                              help: consider mutably borrowing here: `&mut stdout_version`
```

Comment: The compiler tells you what to do. How is applying the suggestion not solving your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your hint... which I simply haven't seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after the comment of mcarton I realised that the `trim_newline` does not return the changed string it is just changing it.

So the final result is this which compiles error free without any warning.

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let result_version = Command::new("git")
        .arg("--version")
        .output()
        .unwrap();

    let rc_version = result_version.status;
    println!("{}", rc_version);

    let mut stdout_version = str::from_utf8(&result_version.stdout).unwrap().to_string();
    trim_newline(&mut stdout_version);

    println!("'{}'", stdout_version);

}

fn trim_newline(s: &mut String) {
    if s.ends_with('\n') {
        s.pop();
        if s.ends_with('\r') {
            s.pop();
        }
    }
}
```